# Need a Python script with MySQl : read value from csv, fetch in db and write it in another file

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am new to Python scripting. Am using  Python 3 and want to script below scenario.

1 csv file has 2k records, only 1 column is present.

```
 Eg : 
Name
Abc
def
Ghi
```

I want to store these strings in a list and use them to fetch in a table using MySQL one by one using for loop.

Say for row in reader:

`query=("select * from table where name=%s", (row)) name_list =cursor. Fetchall()`

Now again after incoming records are store on name_list, I want to write them in a CSV file

Please let me know if am not clear.

Thanks for your valuable help in advance.

Regards,
Sukumar

**Updated**

below is something which i tried. But i am facing problem in data type conversion. The query is asking string value but the value present is byte. am totally new so kindly ignore if something wrong

```
import csv  
import MySQLdb 
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "usr_name", "pwd") 
cursor = db.cursor() 
with open("input_names.csv") as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f) 
    for row in reader: 
        name_list = list(reader) 
        query = ("select * from where name=%s", (i)) 
        cursor.execute(query) 
        details_list = cursor.fetchall()
db.close() 
details = open("output.csv",'wb') 
wr = csv.writer(details, dialect='excel') 
for item in details_list: 
    wr.writerow(item)
```

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing? reading the csv? writing the csv? what is your code written so far?

Comment: below is something which i tried. But i am facing problem in data type conversion. The query is asking string value but the value present is byte. am totally new so kindly ignore if something wrong
import csv

Comment: import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "root", "usr_name", "pwd")
cursor = db.cursor()

with open("input_names.csv") as f:    
 reader = csv.reader(f)    
 for row in reader:        
  name_list = list(reader)        
  query = ("select * from  where name=%s", (i))    
  cursor.execute(query)    
  details_list = cursor.fetchall()

Comment: db.close()

details = open("output.csv",'wb')
wr = csv.writer(details, dialect='excel')
for item in details_list:    
 wr.writerow(item)

Comment: You should post it as part of your question by editing your question. Since you are new, I did it for you. But please check the code indent level to see whether it is correct to your code.

Comment: You are getting error because you are trying to save the file in binary with `wb`, which is expecting byte instead of string. change your code to `details = open('output.csv', 'w')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
names_df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
names_lst = list(names_df['names])

sql_df = pd.DataFrame()
for names in names_lst:
    sql_df = sql_df.append(pd.read_sql('select * from table where name =' + names, con = db_conn_params)
```

Comment: Thank you. I assume i can fetch records with value name with above code but still, how do i get the output records in another list and write it in a csv file ?

Comment: sql_df in the code above is already a Pandas Dataframe. You can write it to a csv file by using the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

Comment: Thanks. I will check and let you know soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information provided, i assumed two scenarios 
1) There is data present in data.csv file, under the column 'NAME'

```
        Name 
        -----
        abc
        def
        ghi
```

2)You need to write the data in a table 
3)Data is retrieved from table and need to write in CSV file

i have using sqlite database to do the work, let me know if  it helps

```
import sqlite3
conn=sqlite3.connect('test.db')
print 'Database created'
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE SAMPLE (NAME   TEXT    NOT NULL);''')
print 'Table created'
#Reading input file 
with open('D:\Users\pankaj-m\Desktop\Stack overflow questions\data.csv','rb') as f:
  reader=csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
      print row
      name_list=list(reader)
#writing to table 
for item in name_list:
    conn.execute('INSERT INTO SAMPLE VALUES (?)',item)
conn.commit()
conn.close()


#Reading from table and writing to file 
conn=sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from SAMPLE")
cursor=cur.fetchall()
with open('D:\Users\pankaj-m\Desktop\Stack overflow questions\data_output.csv','wb') as f1:
    writer=csv.writer(f1)
    for row in cursor:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: pankaj, thanks for coming forward.

I want to a read a csv file which has only one column. want to use each value which is retrieved using select query and fetch it in a database.
the result should be stored in another csv file.

Comment: Looks cool. Will try it some time. Thanks Pankaj.
One change, table is already there all i need is to fetch the value from the table using list value